# Python urlencode does not work when converted into a EXE

Tags: python-2.7

im converting some code to a exe using pyinstaller, when I convert it urlencode stops working. It works before I convert it though, here is my code.

```
import json, time, os, os.path, re, StringIO
from PIL import Image
from urllib import urlencode
import requests, base58
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.parse

    def search(self, CatalogContext = 1, PageNumber = 1, Subcategory = '', Category = '', SortType = '', AggregationFrequency = '', Keyword = ''):
    queryString = {}
    for key, value in locals().items():
        if (key != 'self' and key != 'queryString' and value != ''):
            queryString[key] = value
    queryString = urllib.urlencode(queryString)
    searchURL = 'https://search.roblox.com/catalog/json?{}'.format(queryString)
    try:
        request = requests.get(searchURL.format(queryString))
        if (request.status_code == 200):
            return request.json()
    except:
        pass
    return {}
```

Sorry I had to eat dinner and I didn't explain enough. Once its compiled into a Exe python says that it is not defined.

Comment: What do you mean by "it stops working"?  Describe the symptoms.  (It would probably be easier for you to diagnose this if your code didn't squash exceptions, etcetera.)

Comment: @StephenC Fixed sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have switched python versions accidentally.

In python 3.x, the `urlencode` method is in `urllib.parse`, not `urllib`.

According to these pages:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Comment: No, my python version is 2.7 and I removed parse since that was something i was trying...

Comment: You are missing my point.  If Python is saying that urllib.urlencode is not defined ... which is what you say in your updated question ... then that is a **symptom** that implies you are **actually** using Python 3.   Check that the EXE generator isn't generating an exe that uses Python 3.

Comment: And if this is not the problem, then update you question to say what you mean by *"Once its compiled into a Exe python says that it is not defined."*  What is the "it" you are referring to?